# Windows Azure - CloudStorageAccount parse error

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

I'm getting the following error when I try to get the account:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException

The Conn in configurations are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="WindowsAzureProject3" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration" osFamily="2" osVersion="*" schemaVersion="2013-10.2.2">
  <Role name="manager">
    <Instances count="1" />
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="Conn" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=name;AccountKey=key"></Setting>
    </ConfigurationSettings>
  </Role>
  <Role name="detectrod">
    <Instances count="1" />
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="DataConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=name;AccountKey=key"></Setting>
    </ConfigurationSettings>
  </Role>
</ServiceConfiguration>
```

(the account keys are correct)

and the line with error is:

```
var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("Conn"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error typically happens if your azure code is locally run without the context of azure app fabric or storage account.  i.e. A ROLEENVIRONMENT is not available.

Check if you're not running the code under the context of normal ASP.net context. This could happen if CloudProject is not the startup project and if you directly started the role project.

1. Run Visual Studio as Admin.
2. Ensure Azure Dev Storage emulators are running.
3. Set Cloud project as startup project.
4. Verify again if  `RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable`.

to verify use this code:

```
CloudStorageAccount account = null;

if (RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable)
{
 account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("Conn"));

 // also try
 // account = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount;
}
else
{
 // not in cloud context.
}
```

Comment: the RoleEnvironment is not available. How can I fix this?

Comment: Set the cloud project as your start up project.. Not the specific roles

Comment: edited the answer with better steps and formatted code.. had typed it from phone previously

Comment: One minor correction - You will get `RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable = true` even when your code runs in compute emulator as well. This will be false if the code is not running in either cloud or compute emulator.